# How do I boot back into my MacOS?

Tags: osx, dual-boot

I had a 32GB partition for Ubuntu and then the rest for MacOS. I no longer wanted my Ubuntu partition so I formatted the partition on my MacOS.

I think the boot loader must've been on that partition because I can no longer boot into anything but a live Ubuntu USB.

when I run `efibootmgr -v` it can see my macOS partition (see http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DXFzrz5zny/)

But how can I boot back into my MacOS? :S

Comment: Do you see macOS as an available option if you hold option on power on?

Comment: No, it comes up with a blinking folder with a question mark until I plug the live ubuntu usb in

Answer (score 0):

My Mac knowledge is very sketchy, but since you've had such a hard time getting an answer I thought I'd tell you what I can see...

## What's happened

I'm not convinced that you have destroyed your original boot loader, just the Ubuntu one.  The nice thing about EFI is that bootloaders can be stored side by side where previously you could have only one.

From your pastebin (line 279), the Ubuntu bootloader is set as first boot, with OS X second:

```
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,4d8fdbeb-d6f8-4cce-86f9-f9dff8695276,0x28,0x64000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0080* Mac OS X  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,GPT,cf2dd05b-2789-4d07-83c7-018ae532d035,0x64028,0xe19bfb0)/VenMedia(be74fcf7-0b7c-49f3-9147-01f4042e6842,c005e716a459d9459d1475bbdc249c88)/File(C78C0B9E-B1FA-38E2-8591-C135881B3B4ASystemLibraryCoreServicesboot.efi)
Boot0081* Recovery OS   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,GPT,cf2dd05b-2789-4d07-83c7-018ae532d035,0x64028,0xa60d400)/VenMedia(be74fcf7-0b7c-49f3-9147-01f4042e6842,1be0b02a55ba594f91a1f6008c00aa5c)/File(C78C0B9E-B1FA-38E2-8591-C135881B3B4Aboot.efi)
Boot0082*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,GPT,cf2dd05b-2789-4d07-83c7-018ae532d035,0x64028,0xa60d400)/VenMedia(be74fcf7-0b7c-49f3-9147-01f4042e6842,c005e716a459d9459d1475bbdc249c88)/File(C78C0B9E-B1FA-38E2-8591-C135881B3B4ASystemLibraryCoreServicesboot.efi)
BootFFFF*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(3,GPT,d8d6f046-d9e2-4b48-a5ae-0e225f7926b3,0x7dbffd8,0x4000000)/File(SystemLibraryCoreServicesboot.efi)
```

Ubuntu uses Grub which stores some files (in `/boot/grub`) on Ubuntu's file system.  So when you destroyed Ubuntu, you killed Grub.  But when you installed Ubuntu in the first place you probably didn't overwrite OS X.

## Check if I'm right

You can check if I'm right using your Ubuntu Live USB browse your EFI partiton.  Double check which partition it is (I think `/dev/sdb2`).  Even if it's not labled "EFI" a FAT file system will be the right one:

```
sudo blkid | grep -i fat
/dev/sdb2: UUID="2641-087E" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="27141f73-5de4-4785-8894-3c774fae7e79"
```

Mount the partiton, eg:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/efi
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/efi
```

Then search for "*.efi" files:

```
sudo find /mnt/efi/ -type f -iname '*.efi'
```

Hopefully you will find your bootloader there as well as grub.

## How to fix it

### Best Option - Reconfigure you mac's BIOS / Firmware to boot OSX directly

If you've got this far and shown your old EFI entry exists then this should be simple but ... *Sorry I'm not a mac user*.  I'll keep searching and update this answer if I find it.

### Backup Option - Fix grub

Grub needs its config files to work and you've blown them away.  You can try to rebuild them by taking the files from your live USB.  First update the config on your live USB so that it knows about your system:

```
sudo update-grub
```

*The output should mention Mac OS X if all is fine with OS X*

Now you can either create a new partition to store the config files on, or you can  experiment to see if installing them directly on the EFI partition will work:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/efi/boot
sudo cp -r /boot/grub /mnt/efi/boot/grub
```

Once you've installed them on the hard disk, you can then set grub to find them.  Find the PARTUUID for the partition containing these config files using  `sudo blkid`.  Then  Edit `/mnt/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`:

- replace the UUID for the PARTUUID you just found.
- change the partition number from to the correct `gpt<partition number>`.  Eg `/dev/sdb6` should be `gpt6`:

Example:

```
search.fs_uuid 77b2d888-07e2-4d80-be84-ef1a584a194c root hd0,gpt6
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Comment: hi, it says that the mount point is busy (it's definitely not already mounted), and yes I made the /mnt/efi directory https://i.imgur.com/S92IPQp.png

Comment: That's surprising.  I wouldn't expect the live usb to have mounted anything.  Have you tried `sudo umount /dev/sdb2`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't like it :( I've executed both commands shown here https://i.imgur.com/ya3GqqX.png

Comment: This is slipping outside my knowledge and google isn't giving me anything useful.  You could try asking a new question on this site for this particular problem.  Eg: "Unable to mount Mac's EFI partition from Ubuntu Live USB".  Give the steps you've tried so far and the output from them.  (Copy-paste the output don't use screenshots).  You can add a link back to this question if you want to explain why you need to mount it.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: thank you @philip , you have spent a lot of your personal time trying to help me and i wish to thank you

Comment: but unfortunately it did not go well for me, and i have decided to take my own life. nothing is going well for me and this will be the straw that broke the camels back. goodbye philip, people like you make the world better