# Unable to mount Mac's EFI partition from Ubuntu Live USB

Tags: mount, osx, uefi

I've tried to mount my mac's EFI partiton while using an ubuntu live USB, however I get the following errors:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/efi
mount: /mnt/efi: /dev/sdb2 already mounted or mount point busy.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo umount /dev/sdb2
umount: /dev/sdb2: not mounted
```

And yes /mnt/efi is a directory that I made.

Previously, I tried to run boot-repair, here is the output log from that http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DXFzrz5zny/

And here is my previous network question, [How do I boot back into my MacOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516095/how-do-i-boot-back-into-my-macos)

Comment: Will it be sdb or sda?

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/efi
mount: /mnt/efi: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.